# application.js can't find jquery.ui.effect-blind

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, jquery-ui

I'm trying to use the gem jquery-rails but my application.js file hasn't been able to find the necessary file ("couldn't find file 'jquery.ui.effect-blind'")

My application.js:

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery.ui.effect-blind
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require turbolinks
//= require_tree .
```

And in my gemfile, I have:

```
gem 'jquery-rails', "2.3.0"
gem 'jquery-ui-rails'
```

I've seen this question asked a couple times before and most people reported it being fixed by using the 2.3.0 version of 'jquery-rails'. I've specified it and confirmed it with the gem list command, but the application.js file still can't find it. I've tried jquery.ui and jquery.ui.all, but these give the same error.

Answer (score 89, accepted):

I ran into a similar issue and it turned out  that at some point they started using `jquery-ui` instead of `jquery.ui` and `/` instead of `.` to include individual parts. Try using:

```
//= require jquery-ui/effect-blind
```

**EDIT**:

In the recent version there is an extra `effects` in the path

```
//= require jquery-ui/effects/effect-blind
```

Comment: 10x! made me able to proceed with _Iteration F3: highlighting changes_ in Pragmatic's _Agile Web Development with Rails 4_

Comment: Also, it might be worthy to mention, please Restart the rails Server after adding gem for the same.

Comment: @ Kyle Decot sorry after restarting my server it went through.

Answer (score 10):

I had to change it to

```
//= require jquery-ui/effects/effect-blind
```

This seems to be the recent one.

https://github.com/jquery-ui-rails/jquery-ui-rails